# In Rails, for a given request who responds to the client - controller or view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I came across 2 images showing MVC implementation in Rails.

1.

[image: 1.]

2.

[image]

In first case, the View returns HTML to the controller. In the second case, the view responds directly to the client.

I have seen both this concepts explained in multiple sites. However, which is technically more correct? Between the 'Controller' and the View who really respond to the client directly?

Answer (score 0):

The Controller is like a middle man between Model and View.
Controller returns data to render in View.

Answer (score 0):

The both cases are actually the same, it's just that the second diagram shows a slightly simplified process, with steps 7 and 8 merged into a single step. So, technically, the first diagram is more correct. It's the controller that does the responding with HTML code, which was generated in the view. The view's job is to construct the HTML from the `erb` template.

Comment: Thanks @p4sh4. Both cases are really not same. We have 2 choices and only one can be true - 'The View directly responds to the client and not involving the controller at all' OR 'View returns HTML to controller and controller returns to client'. Can you help me this?

Comment: 'View returns HTML to controller and controller returns to client' is the answer.